# Power BI: Date column not processed correctly using R script

Tags: r, powerbi

In Power BI, I am trying to transform my data table prior to visualization. I have chosen to do so using R script.

My data table contains a 'Date' column. Whenever I run my R script on the column, it returns NULL for all values in that column.

For example -

**Before**

[image]

**R Script used to transform column**

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

# Extract month-year for each date
df=dataset %>%
   mutate(Date=as.yearmon(Date))
```

**Result**

[image]

I re-executed this script in R Studio, and the transformation works perfectly fine.

Seems to be an issue with Power BI, any date-related operation results in `NULL`s

Anybody experiencing the same, with a possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Date` is the name of a class, perhaps you try to fully qualify the column name, eg. `dataset$Date`

Comment: No need to specify the column name in that format when using the pipe operator. That's not what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`This answer has been edited after a discussion in the comments`

---

I have a suggestion assuming your desired output looks like this:

[image]

The key to the solution lies in converting your dates to `text` before running the R script, and treat the input in your R script accordingly. Also, to make sure the `Power Query Editor` doesn't make any formatting choices for you (avoid dates as decimals), your output dates from your R script should be formatted as `text / string`.

---

**My approach:**

**1.** Manually insert a few dates using `Enter Data`:

[image]

**2.** Go to `Edit Queries` and take a look:

[image]

Notice that the column has been automaticaly changed to `Date`, and there's a step `Changed Type` under `Applied Steps`. Now, change the Date data type to `text` and replace the other data changing step:

[image]

**3.** Insert the following R script that only has a few changes compared to your setup:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

# Extract month-year for each date
df=dataset %>%
   mutate(Date=as.yearmon(as.Date(Date,format = "%d/%m/%Y")))

# Make sure Power BI picks up the date column as a string format
df['Date'] <- format(df['Date'], "%b %Y")
```

**4.** Run the script to get this:

[image]

I hope this is what you were looking for. Don't hesitate to let me know if not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. In fact I tried the same. I first converted the date column to text. Then executed the R script in the same manner. And the result was exactly what you got. The dates were converted to some kind of decimal numbers. However the `as.yearmon` function should return a year-month combination. For example, `21/03/2018` would become `March 2018`. Which is not happening.

Comment: @Varun Then I guess we'll go for "text in, text out", and handle the rest inside the R script, so that the next step in power bi is "march 2018" as a string. Should be easy, but I'm not on my PC right now. I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: @Varun Add another line at the end of the script and try `df['Date'] <- format(df['Date'], "%Y %b")` and see how that goes.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly well when you create the data in Power BI and then run the R script. But with my existing dataset, the steps don't result in the same outcome. The difference between both being that with the existing dataset, converting from date to text results in a change in the format of the date. So `20/01/2019` becomes `20-01-2019`. And then the R script results in NULLs. However if the same dates are entered manually in Power BI in the same format, it works. Not sure why the text conversion step results in different outcomes for the same data..

Comment: @Varun Your screenshot displays the dates as `20/02/2019`. It's not easy to tell if that's the actual form of your data, or just they way PowerBI represents it. Do you have a sample of your *actual* data that you cold add in the question?

Comment: In the end, your solution worked when I first converted the date to text in Excel itself, and after uploading the file in Power BI, I did the same conversion to text in Power BI before running the script.

Comment: @Varun I'm glad to hear that! Using R (and Python) in Power BI is really cool, but it sure isn't easy! Let's hope the Power BI dev team increases their focus on these things in the time to come.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio, i get :

```
as.yearmon("21/02/2019")
[1] NA
```

Try:

```
as.yearmon(as.Date("21/02/2019","%d/%m/%Y"))
[1] "Feb 2019"
```

Comment: I can't do much without a reproducible example. I don't know PowerBI. Maybe load the data from powerBI as character and paste it here..